# Discrete Math - relations

Tags: discrete-mathematics, relations

I really tried to understand what this definition of a relation means, but I just couldn't figure it out. Therefore, I would appreciate any kind of hints or explanation very much.

**Let us denote elements of $\mathbb{R}^2$ by $x = (x_1,x_2)$. Let '~' be a relation on $\mathbb{R}^2$, defined as x ~ y if $x_1 < y_1$ or ($x_1 = y_1$ and $x_2 \leq y_2$).
Give examples of three different tuples x,y,z elements of $\mathbb{R}^2$, s.t. x~y and $x_1=z_1$, x~z**

Does it mean that if $x$ is in relation to $y$, $x_1$ has to be either smaller than $y_1$ or have the same value and also $x_2$ being smaller than or equal to $y_2$?

What do the $x_1,x_2$ and $y_1,y_2$ refer to?

Would it be then something like:
$x= 1$,
$y= 3$,
$z= 1$

(1,1), (3,3), (1,3)?

Thank you so much for your help!

[Here is the original picture of the exercise:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HwQVt.jpg)

Comment: Please edit to include your efforts.  Can you find distinct $x,y$ with $x\sim y$? With $x_1=y_1$?

Comment: In your example:  We have $(1,1)\sim (3,3)$ since $x_1=1<3=y_1$.  And we have $(1,1)\sim (1,3)$ since $x_1=y_1$ and $x_2<y_2$.  So that triple is satisfactory.

Comment: Ah, so that is how it works! Thank you so much, this is truly a huge help!